# How to create Sequence No for sub item by using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is a table in databasse.

A is main item . 
aas,asd and ads is sub item of A

B is main item . 
byw  and bmw is sub item of A

```
  ____Main Item_____|________Sub Item_______
          A         |          aas                             
          A         |          asd
          A         |          ads
          B         |          byw
          B         |          bmw
```

I need to display like these.
It will added SEQ_NO column..

```
  ____Main Item_____|_____SEQ_NO___|____Sub Item_______
          A         |       1      |      aas                             
          A         |       2      |      asd
          A         |       3      |      ads
          B         |       1      |      byw
          B         |       2      |      bmw
```

I use sql server.

Comment: please tag your database engine

Comment: How is this ordered? How come `asd` comes after `aas`, but before `ads`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number` function to generate the seq_no column. Also change the `sub_item` ordering as per your requirements.

```
select main_item,
row_number() over(partition by main_item order by sub_item) as seq_no,
sub_item 
from tablename
```